# Run JS function from parent window in child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to run javascript function from parent window in child window

**Example**

I have to different websites let's say `site1.com` and `site2.com`

I want from `site1.com` to open new window of URL `site2.com`

```
new_window = window.open("site2.com/index.php", "window2");
```

Then i want to run a js function `test()` on this new_window.

```
// Where site2.com/index.php 
<html>
    ......
</html>
<script>
   function test(){
    // some code here
   }
</script>
```

**Summary**

Want to open new window (child) and run some JS functions from parent window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [cross document messaging](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) to circumvent the same origin policy as follows.

Parent window (`site1.com`):

```
var site2 = window.open("http://site2.com");
site2.postMessage("test", "http://site2.com");
```

Child window (`site2.com`):

```
function test() {
    // some code here
}

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://site1.com") {
        var funct = window[event.data];
        if (typeof funct === "function")
            funct();
    }
}, false);
```

This is a simple example. You could make it more sophisticated to allow callbacks, return values, etc. but that would require a blog post to be fully explained.

You may read more about `window.postMessage` on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

Note however that the following example will not work in Internet Explorer (obviously).

Comment: That is a great example @Aadit M Shah

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to run your function from the child window if it's not on the same domain for security reasons.

Comment: Actually you can. All you have to do is use `postMessage` to create your own dispatcher function.

Comment: @AaditMShah could you plz give me example to understand what you mean ?